# Is the present participle phrase correctly used to establish cause and effect relationship?

Tags: present-participles, adverbials

> She brought fourteen children to term and lost four of them, *leaving her with ten kids who ranged in age from Anne, who was twenty, to Billy and Jim, the sweet-eyed twins, who were six*.

<sup>From *Say Nothing* by Patrick Radden Keefe</sup>

The participle must modify a noun/phrase or a pronoun. In the aforementioned sentence, the Subject "She" doesn't seem to go well with the participle "leaving her with....".

Comment: [Related and probable duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/594690/2085). Your mistake is in thinking that the gerundial-participial clause "must" modify an NP: [Participial phrases may act as modifiers for any construct that can take a modifier](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/301514/2085). ***Obviously,*** this modifier clause is working like how "sentence adverbs" work, exactly like how *obviously* worked in this sentence.

Comment: I don't understand why you say *"She" doesn't seem to go well with the participle "leaving her with...."* (the cited text is syntactically fine, in case you didn't realize). Note that semantically, ***leaving*** here is identical to ***which left~** [her with 10 surviving children]*, so that substitution can be made with no other changes. Alternatively, you could end the first sentence with a full stop after ***them***, and start a new sentence with ***She was left** [with 10 children...]* if you want to use ***she*** as the SUBJECT, rather than ***her*** as the OBJECT.

Comment: I would prefer _which left her_, since she didn't leave herself with ten children.

Comment: @KateBunting: That might depend on how she "lost" them (as Oscar Wilde might have said in relation to husbands! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why, because you feel that explaining that participial clauses can be sentence adverbials is somehow better suited to ELL than to ELU?

Comment: Rephrasing my concern that "She" doesn't go well with the participle "leaving her.."

She leaving herself with 10 kids... seems awkward

Comment: @tchrist: "participial clauses can be sentence adverbials" is a very "technical" way of referring to what any (Anglophone) fule kno - *It left **her** with 10 kids*, not *It left **she** with 10 kids*. I don't believe the target audience of ELU should need to have that pointed out.

Comment: @rahulsehrawat: - as Kate points out, *she didn't **leave herself** with 10 kids*. It can only really be the passive construction *She **was left** with...*

Comment: I never thought I'd say this, but ... comments are not for extended discussion.

Comment: While "which left her with" is an alternate phrasing, I seen nothing wrong with the original wording. @KateBunting

Comment: @FumbleFingers   Is the following construction equivalent to the one stated in question

X's dog died, leaving him in despair.

Comment: I pointedly didn't say the OP's version was wrong, just that I preferred mine.

Comment: @KateBunting: OP's version in the question is "acceptable", but ignoring the possibilities of the Oscar Wilde quip, OP's subsequent rephrasing in a comment to *She [is] leaving herself with 10 kids* isn't really acceptable, because that format implies "positive action" on her part (not necessarily *deliberate*, though).

Comment: [sentence relative clause](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/610566/i-need-help-with-independent-clauses/610584#610584)

Answer (score 0):

It depend entirely on the voice of the overall piece. Many novels are written as a narrative which tells a story from the past, in which case everything ought to be told in the past tense (eg "*once upon a time there **was** a girl named Anne who **was** twenty*").

Yes, it would be unusual - wrong - for somebody to say in conversation that their child "*was* twenty" if they are talking about their age *now*, but if they were speaking about a past event they would in fact be saying "she was twenty *at the time*".

Answer (score 0):

*leaving her* means the same here as **which left her**:

> She brought fourteen children to term and lost four of them, **which left her** with ten kids ...

The relative pronoun **which** refers to the preceding clause *She brought fourteen children to term and lost four of them*, the **situation**.

> The situation left her with ten kids ...

The understood "subject" of *leaving* is the same as the antecedent of **which**: the **situation**.